# How to identify which certificate I'm missing to produce HTTPS calls?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

I posted a [question similar to this one on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59579902/336648), but that has not produced any answers so far, so I'm hoping someone here will be able to help me out.

Somewhat simplified, I'm trying to do a POST request via https using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (later I'm hoping to reproduce it in PL/SQL under Oracle using UTL_HTTP), but I'm having some certificate-related issues. I have a specific url I'll be trying to reach later, but for testing purposes, I've been using a [webhook url](https://webhook.site/) just to verify that I could make calls out at all.

I *am able* to perform a post request to a https-address if I disable **SSL Certificate Verification** under the Postman settings - so it's apparently possible to reach an outside url, so long as I don't care about the validity of the certificates used.

**Proxy issues**
I my problems are due to the fact that I'm behind a proxy at the organization I'm currently working for. If I look at the certificate path for the cert for [webhook.site](https://webhook.site) for instance, it looks like the following, where the grayed out parts of cert names are names related to the organization.

[image]

The result of this is that when I try to perform https POST requests to webhook **without disabling cert verification**, it fails with the following error shown in my Postman console:

> Error: unable to verify the first certificate.

**Attempted solutions**
A couple of things I've experimented with to try to solve this:

- Importing and adding any or all of the certs from the certification path shown above into my cert store.
- Importing the certs into Postman (under **Settings > Certificates**) - although I'm far from certain that I've done this correctly, or if this is even the right way to go about it.

My hunch is that I just need to get the correct certificate installed in the correct place in order for this to work. The problem is I can't figure out which certificate that should be in this case (or where it should be installed for that matter, though I would assume that adding it under *trusted root certificates* in the system cert store should suffice?).

Are these assumptions correct? Any tips on how I can figure out exactly which certificate I'm actually missing?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the client - postman - cannot verify the server certificate. My assumption based on the information you provided is that your organization's proxy acts as a Man-In-The-Middle and terminates SSL at the proxy. As a result, you recieve a certificate signed by your organization rather than something signed by a trusted certificate authority.

The solutions to this is adding the signing authority as trusted CA on the client side.

Comment: That matches my own theory pretty well. I assume what you mean is that I need to add the root cert from the cert path shown in the image as a trusted CA? I.e. add it to the *Trusted Root Certificates* under the *Certificates* snap-in in MMC? I've tried this, but not had any success so far, unfortunately. Please let me know if I've misunderstood what you meant here.

Comment: @Kjartan: Not every application is using the Windows trust store. Looks like postman is using its own and only recently added a way to import CA into this - see https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3290

Comment: If the intention is just to verify whether adding the certificate eliminates the cert error, why don't you try it with curl and a custom cert bundle? A little googling would get you more details on how to do this.